# Ruby on Rails trouble with getting JSON from external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I can't seem to figure out how to make an API call to a URI like:

```
http://elophant.com/api/v1/na/getSummonerNames?summonerIds=7428,26670961,12468&key=APIKey
```

Where summonerIds are the IDs of the players in the game and the key is the API key to access the API.

When I run it in the browser it returns (with the actual API key, of course):

```
["Phreak","Test","OranGe"]
```

When I run try to access it in my main controller for my Rails app by doing:

```
require 'net/http'
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def player 
    @player = params[:player]

    url = URI.parse('http://elophant.com/api/v1/na/getSummonerNames?summonerIds=' +     @player + '&key=APIKey')
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
    res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
    http.request(req)
    }
    @b = res.body 
  end
end
```

(Where it says "&key=APIKey", I would replace APIKey with the actual API key.)

then print out the @b in my player.html.erb:

```
<%= @b %>
```

it returns:

```
v1 getSummonerNames
```

which is the exact same response I get in the browser if I don't provide an API key, but I do provide an API key in the URL in the code.

So my question is, how do I get the browser to use the API key to get a response?

Thank you,

Alex D.